# Getting WETH from ETH on Hardhat Local Network

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, wrapped-tokens

I have a localhost Hardhat Network running but I need to convert Fake ETH on it into WETH.
How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to create an ERC20 called WETH.
Something like:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract WETHToken is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("Wrapped ETHER", "WETH") {
        _mint(<msg.sender or your address>, 9999 ether);
    }
}
```

So when you `npx hardhat node`, you'll have to [deploy that contract](https://hardhat.org/guides/deploying).